# Only allow questions to be deleted if a downvoted answer or no answer is present

Tags: feature-request, deleted-questions

### Current situation

Currently the following rule applies when deleting questions:

- Questions can be deleted if no (upvoted) answer is present

The rationale behind it is probably that, in case an answer is posted that has value, it is assumed that that answer has been upvoted at least once, so the question can not be removed anymore.

I understand what's happening here, but this generally does not apply to niche tags, where the only vote you usually get is the one from the OP. Only if a question has a really great value you could get another upvote.

I'm noticing (even today), that some OPs are deleting questions after they're provided with an answer for no good reason at all. The answer might have no votes (yet), but the OP's deletion is just faster than the upvote that may come.
I don't think this is a positive thing for a website that aims at having a great collection of frequently (and less frequently) asked questions and answers.

---

### My suggestion

My suggestion is that questions can only be removed if no answer with more or **equal than** zero votes is present. This means that neutral answers (+ answers that might be assumed to be valuable in the future) prevent questions from deleted as well.

Also, if the answer is downvoted, there should be a check if the downvote is from the OP, because if the downvote is from the OP, it doesn't really work either. Ok, it will cost them some reputation points, but I assume that after deleting the question the reputation points are restored again. If that's not the case we could of course leave this check behind.

Comment: question is: can you flag a question for moderators attention when it's deleted? You should have reference to your answer - therefore you may be able to flag the answer and explain what has happened in the custom box. It's not an everyday situation but when it happens I don't think it would take a moderator too long to undelete the question.

Comment: @mehow - yes you can flag a deleted question,

Comment: @ChrisF really, how do you do that? When I go to the question I get the "Page Not Found" webpage with the reason "This question was voluntarily removed by its author."

Comment: @DimitriM - you need 10k rep to be able to see deleted posts. I should have made that clear.

Comment: Another thing you don't get if you're primarily active in niche tags :p