# Deleting a valid question on purpose

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

I've seen this couple of times, but [this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886507/changing-all-ldur-to-an-add-and-a-ld) (10k+) it hit me and I decided to get attention on how some users are misusing Stack Overflow for their own purpose.

In short, it looks like some students are asking very specific, valid questions, and as soon as there's a valid answer (or end of a test) they wipe the history to (probably) avoid being caught by their teachers. Last time I've seen this was most likely a question from a job interview.

I'm not angry and all, but I just want to bring attention to a possible improvement. Perhaps not giving the possibility to delete own answer if user rep is below some small limit and if there's no question downvotes and answers.

Comment: This question is quite similar, but more general: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316117/what-to-do-when-a-question-you-answered-gets-deleted-intentionally. There were also a feature request that the OP shouldn't be able to delete a question anymore when the question received an answer, even if that answer has no upvotes. Maybe I can find it.

Comment: This question has the same feature request: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261666/only-allow-questions-to-be-deleted-if-a-downvoted-answer-or-no-answer-is-present

Comment: @Tom Thanks. Brad Larson in the first link you provided highlighted that *self-deletions count against you in the question-ban heuristics, so if they do this repeatedly they will quickly find themselves unable to ask any questions at all*.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs [But how many times is enough?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311812/424903) :)

Comment: In my opinion it is more important that users should be able to delete bad questions upon self-realization, than to keep test cheaters at bay. The latter isn't SO's problem, but schools that don't understand that you can't allow phones during tests. In many cases the user is kind enough to provide their name and university, so feel free to contact their uni. It's not SO's business.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs the point in self-deletions and question ban is that I assume many of these users don't care about that: they just create a new account

Comment: @Kaddath And there are systems in place specifically to slow those people down.  We understand people create new accounts to get around the question ban, and while we're okay with allowing them to do so in most cases, they're going to get *heavily* throttled, to the point of a single question a week.  That dramatically limits the amount of damage they can do.

Comment: Technically there is no real damage in the situation sketched here. People post a question and then delete it again. The world will keep spinning. What will grind the gears is that people get away with it pretty much scot-free and you can't really know what is going to happen when posting an answer, so you will see your effort be spit back at you. IMO: that is the true test. You have to be able to deal with that kind of nonsense because it will happen, we can't wish it away.

Comment: @Lundin It's not just an exam problem. Most schools have strict policies against academic dishonesty. If the asker were to pass off Andrejs' answer as their own response to assigned course work, that would constitute academic dishonesty in most cases. Deleting the question prevents someone (even a 10k+ user) from searching via Google or trawling through SO to find evidence.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have basic protections in place to stave off this sort of abuse. The system automatically blocks self-deletion of a question when that question:

- has an answer with at least one upvote (regardless of the answer's net score),
- has multiple answers (regardless of votes),
- has an accepted answer, or
- has an answer that has been awarded a bounty.

This is designed to prevent someone from asking a question, getting (a) good answer(s), and then deleting the question, thus throwing away the effort of the answerers and robbing the rest of us of that value.

The edge case here is when the time elapsed between posting of the answer and deletion of the question is very small. If the community hasn't had a chance to review and vote on the answer, then there will be no upvotes on the answer to block deletion.

On the other hand, we really don't want to prevent people from cleaning up their own garbage, so I'm not convinced that it makes sense for these rules to be any more strict.

**If you witness an edge case, where something of true value is being thrown away by the original asker, please flag it for moderator attention.** We will be happy to step in and undelete it. Use a custom flag, and explain *clearly* why you are flagging (the question has been deleted by the asker), what you want a moderator to do (please undelete the question), and why (because it is a useful question that has received a good answer, which will be of value to others in the future).

In [this specific case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54886507/changing-all-ldur-to-an-add-and-a-ld), for what it's worth, I wholeheartedly agree with you. That was a good question, and it should not have been deleted. (The community already handled undeleting it.) I can't really understand why the question was scored at −2 when I looked at it, either. I personally think it's worth an *upvote*, and I have pretty high standards. I can only assume those downvotes rolled in before it was edited.

Comment: Given the reasoning here, it would seem like there's an easy solution:  Once the first answer is posted, the question can't be deleted for X minutes, no matter the votes (giving it a chance to fulfill those other requirements, or fail and allow people to clean up later).

Comment: Good point, @Izkata. Hadn't thought of that. Maybe worth a [meta-tag:feature-request] if you have the time.